# MVC open jquery dialog when the controller has issue with data from view

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

This should be easy. I'm probably making it much, much more difficult than necessary.

When a user completes information in my view and clicks the submit button, my controller checks the data entered against what is already in the database. If the information already exists, I want the controller to invoke a popup in the view letting them know that they cannot continue because the data already exists.

All of the example code seems to insist I click something before a dialog opens, but I want the controller (using AJAX?)(somehow?) to tell the view to display the dialog.

Any examples, sans the ones that want me to click on something to open the dialog, would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

1. Make Submit button to normal button.

2.onclick on of this button make ajax call to check whether data is duplicate or not.Return true or false from controller.

3.If it's true means data is duplicate,invoke jquery dialog. `$("#div").dialog();`

4.If its' false means data is valid,invoke form submit.`$(form).submit();`

Comment: Exactly the nudge I was looking for. It's taking me some time to understand why/how things are done in a web environment, but comments like yours really help further my understanding. Thank you!